# URL Rewrite code is not working on my .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting, url-rewrite-module

**My Original URL**

> http://www.mcoh.co.in/blog-single?category=Blog&id=Janurary%202018%20Product%20training%20Scores

**and Expecting in:**

> http://www.mcoh.co.in/mcohBlog/Janurary%202018%20Product%20training%20Scores

But Am receiving same url as original.

```
## hide .php extension
# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NC]

## To internally redirect /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^mcoh([^/]*)/([^/]*)\$ /blog-single?category=$1&id=$2 [L]
```

Comment: So you want your url without the .php or with? I don't get it. Your first rule will remove the php. Which you will get in your "original" url so where's the problem?

Comment: wait, so your first rule will remove the .php and your second rule will re-add the .php? what? can you be more precise or at least tell us what you really want? Do you want to "convert" your original url to your expecting url? is that it?

Comment: @DiogoJesus leave about.php in rewrite rule, Am Expecting this url:  http://www.mcoh.co.in/mcohBlog/Janurary%202018%20Product%20training%20Scores

Answer (score 0):

Your problem with this line :

```
RewriteRule ^mcoh([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.php$ /blog-single?category=$1&id=$2 [L]
```

replace it with :

```
RewriteRule ^mcoh([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /blog-single?category=$1&id=$2 [L]
```

The extension is already removed by previous rule .

Moreover , your code should look like this :

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]
RewriteRule ^mcoh([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /blog-single?category=$1&id=$2 [L,NE]
```

Comment: after putting htaccess code also my url is not rewritten to that specific manner. its appearing in this manner alone http://www.mcoh.co.in/blog-single?category=Blog&id=Janurary%202018%20Product%20training%20Scores remove those blog-single?category=Blog should be replaced as mcohBlog

Comment: even after clearing the caches and history also am getting the same url which am passing. it is not rewritten

Comment: @JEEVA yes , internally redirection from /mcohBlog/Janurary%202018%20Product%20training%20Scores to original  one /blog-single?category=Blog&id=Janurary%202018%20Product%20training%20Scores

Comment: you are telling me to remove which line Mr.@Mohammed Elhag.

Comment: @JEEVA i said replace it , save your code and copy my code and test it as it is , clear cache first

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?mcohBlog/([^/d]+)/?$ blog-single.php?category=Blog&id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Can you try this? Just add this rewriterule at the end of your code. and remove your last line of code

---

### EDIT

Also your code organization is very wrong. That's why it's not working as expected

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews     
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]
RewriteRule ^/?mcohBlog/([^/d]+)/?$ blog-single.php?category=Blog&id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

This should be your last code

Answer (score 0):

To redirect/rewrite

```
http://www.mcoh.co.in/blog-single?category=Blog&id=Janurary%202018%20Product%20training%20Score
```

to

```
http://www.mcoh.co.in/mcohBlog/Janurary%202018%20Product%20training%20Scores
```

put the following at the top of your htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on

#To externally redirect /blog-single?category=foo&id=bar to /mochBlog/bar
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^category=([^&]+)&id=(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ /mochBlog/%2? [R,L]
#To internally redirect /mochBlog/bar to /blog-single?category=foo&id=bar
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^mochBlog/(.+)$ /blog-single?category=blog&id=$1 [L]
```